# IOS, how and where to declare a private variable

Tags: ios, private-members

On obj-c, when will i declare a private variable in header file. like below 

    `@interface Contact : NSObject{
        NSString *name;
        NSUInteger age;
    }`

define a private variable, it can't be access by any instance. why there is need to do it. i think this scene is no need to exist.

now, i want to know which scene will use such way to declare variable, the advantage use this way.

Comment: Inside .m file you can declare.

Comment: Thanks quickly reply. yeah, i know .m file i can declare, but on .h file also can declare. when will i declare on .h file

Comment: Please go through the basic objective-c books or better to search through this site. There are many answers given to your question. The requirement is all dependent on your programming logic. When there is a use of protected kind of members then we use to declare in .h

Comment: that is lots of possible duplicate answer. User must do some RND and please read that duplicate answer ther is 7 answer with lots of link.